# Trying to install epel-release on Fedora 30 -- no match for argument: epel-release

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, fedora

I'm on Fedora 30. I am trying to install "epel-release".

I am following this guide: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/standalone/install/oss/el7/ -- I am unable to successfully run the command:

```
$ sudo yum install -y epel-release yum-utils
```

I get as a result:

```
No match for argument: epel-release
```

So, I tried the following commands from this article: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-epel-repository/

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
$ yum install ./epel-release-latest-*.noarch.rpm
```

No such luck - this is the output:

```
Error: 
  Problem: problem with installed package fedora-release-workstation-30-1.noarch
   - package epel-release-7-11.noarch conflicts with fedora-release provided by fedora-release-workstation-30-1.noarch
   - package epel-release-7-11.noarch conflicts with fedora-release provided by fedora-release-workstation-30-4.noarch
   - conflicting requests
```

I have also tried:

```
$ sudo dnf install epel-relase
```

which that didn't work either, here's the results:

```
No match for argument: epel-release
Error: Unable to find a match
```

I have come across several different articles basically saying to either use the first command listed or variations of the second command I've tried - all unsuccessful. side note: Is this because Fedora 30 was just "recently" released?

My end goal is to deploy a Ruby on Rails web app internally using Nginx. For that, I am following this guide: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/ruby/ownserver/nginx/oss/el7/deploy_app.html

Any direction for how to install epel-release would be great as I can't move forward until passenger is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so turns out that this can be simplified to just:

```
$ sudo dnf install passenger
```

Crazy that they have an entire tutorial for how to install passenger when it can just be simplified to this one line.

Comment: EPEL is a Fedora subproject which builds packages from the Fedora collection on the Red Hat Enterprise Linux platform. If you want these packages and are on RHEL, you need to enable EPEL. If you want them on a Fedora OS (Fedora Server, Fedora Workstation, etc.), they're already available by default.

Comment: @mattdm ahh I see -- so the trick is to enable EPEL. Thank you - I did not know this.

Comment: Well, again, that "trick" is necessary on RHEL, but not on Fedora OSes.

Comment: @mattdm Oh I see.

Comment: "Error: Unable to find a match: passenger"
You need to add what repo even has "passenger" listed.

Answer (score 14):

Note that [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) is not suitable for use in Fedora! Fedora is not Enterprise Linux. EPEL provides "a high quality set of additional packages **for Enterprise Linux**, including, but not limited to, Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), CentOS and Scientific Linux (SL), Oracle Linux (OL)". Put simply, *Enterprise Linux* is a term that refers to *Red Hat Enterprise Linux* or one of its clones. And Fedora is not a Red Hat clone.

That is why you cannot install the "epel-release" package in Fedora. It simply does not exist. Don't try to use EPEL on Fedora.

As noted before, the Fedora repositories provide most (if not all) of the EPEL packages. Additional software for Fedora is available in the [RPMFusion](https://rpmfusion.org/) repositories. In their own words, RPMFusion is "an extension of Fedora" that "provides software that the Fedora Project or Red Hat doesn't want to ship." RPMFusion can not be used on Enterprise Linux. You could see RPMFusion as the "EPEL alternative" for Fedora, but be aware that the software collections provided by RPMFusion and EPEL are entirely unrelated and uncomparable.

EPEL is managed from within the Fedora project, and thus part of Red Hat. RPMFusion is an independent organization. You can consider their repositories reliable, but always be cautious when you install software from external sources.

Finally - on a sidenote - on recent Fedora versions, 'dnf' has [replaced](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/guide-yum-dnf) 'yum'.

Answer (score 3):

you'll need to install the EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) repository.
The EPEL project is run by the Fedora team.
When you install third-party repositories on Red Hat and CentOS systems.
Install in centos:

```
sudo yum install yum-plugin-priorities epel-release
```

When the installation completes, navigate to the /etc/yum.repos.d directory,
and open the **CentOS-Base.repo** file in your favorite text editor.
After the last line of the base, updates, and extras sections, add the line: `priority=1`.
After the last line of the centosplus section, add the line:
`priority=2`.
Save the file and close the editor.
Now, Open the **epel.repo** file for editing.
After the last line of the epel section,add the line:
 `priority=10`. 
After the last line of each remaining section, add the line:
 `priority=11`.
Update the system and then create a list of the installed and available packages by running:

```
sudo yum upgrade
sudo yum list > yum_list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

For RHEL - dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm

Try with the above command to install epel-release in RHEL 8